# Batch-correct incorrectly formatted XML files

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have 300+ XML files that look like this:

```
<SUBJECT>
  <TITLE>Mathematics</TITLE> 
  <AREA>
    <TITLE>Geometry</TITLE> 
    <SECTION>
      <TITLE>Coordinate Geometry</TITLE> 
      <TOPIC GRADELEVEL="10">
        <TITLE>Plotting Ordered Pairs </TITLE> 
        // Lots of content
      </TOPIC> 
    </SECTION> 
  </AREA> 
</SUBJECT>
(eof)
```

It **SHOULD** read like so:

```
<SUBJECT>
  <TITLE>Mathematics</TITLE>
</SUBJECT>
<AREA>
  <TITLE>Geometry</TITLE>
</AREA>
<SECTION>
  <TITLE>Coordinate Geometry</TITLE>
</SECTION>
<TOPIC GRADELEVEL="10">
  <TITLE>Plotting Ordered Pairs </TITLE>
</TOPIC> 
// Lots of content
```

Does there exist there a batch solution to correct this?

Comment: "does there exist"? I'm quite sure, the answer is no. Can it be built? probably yes (when all 300+ files have the very same structure). But to be honest: batch really isn't a good tool for such things. Consider Powershell.

Comment: You have to write a script.  Or find someone who will do it for you.

Comment: This is done best by using [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt).

Comment: Powershell, Vbscript and Jscript all of methods to read and write XML files. Batch files just see everything as a lines of text and treats all variables as strings.  You will have better luck with the first three scripting languages.

Comment: How is a script supposed to know which information you want moving out of `<AREA>` and `<SECTION>` etc.? Also your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - will look into writing a script. Apologies if this was off-topic - still quite new to SO :)

Comment: I think it's only off-topic because the people who hang out on the batch-file tag aren't XML types. Just delete the "batch-file" tag and you'll be fine.

Comment: Your desired output format isn't well-formed XML because there's no enclosing element. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @MichaelKay, their question is specific, "Does there exist there a batch solution to correct the format of 300+ XML files from X to Y?" They haven't asked for us to create a solution, they want us to provide them with a pre-existing one. They are using Stack Overflow as a search engine. Requests for software/tools, _(an existing batch solution)_, are off-topic. The intention is that the OP creates their own batch solution, seeking help with it, should it fail to achieve their goal. We are not free code writers or search monkeys, they've asked for our time & effort yet provided none in return.

Comment: @Compo you have a different reading of the question from mine. My reading is "is there a way of solving this problem in a batch job".

Comment: @MichaelKay, if it's just a batch job and not a batch file, the specifically used batch-file tag, _(take a look at it's description)_, should be removed. If a batch file is required then the answer is just, yes with the aid of other tools or languages. Either way the remit of this forum isn't to code solutions for free for those who come here simply asking for everything whilst showing no attempt towards that goal themselves. In fairness to the OP, they haven't asked for us to code a solution, they've merely asked if one exists, and the first comment clearly and succinctly answers that.

Comment: @Compo I don't read "is there a solution" as "is there an off-the-shelf solution", I read it as "can this problem be solved".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an XSLT processor (like `xsltproc` for Linux). You have to surround your input XML with a `root` element for the XML to be valid.
Then use this XSLT-1.0 file (`theAbove.xslt`) for transforming your XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SUBJECT | AREA | SECTION | TOPIC">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="TITLE" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<SUBJECT>
    <TITLE>Mathematics</TITLE>
</SUBJECT>
<AREA>
    <TITLE>Geometry</TITLE>
</AREA>
<SECTION>
    <TITLE>Coordinate Geometry</TITLE>
</SECTION>
<TOPIC GRADELEVEL="10">
    <TITLE>Plotting Ordered Pairs </TITLE>
</TOPIC>
```

Call it with

```
xsltproc theAbove.xslt yourSource.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The Saxon XSLT processor allows you to specify a directory containing source documents on the input line:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:inputdir -o:outputdir -xsl:theAbove.xslt
```

which has the advantage that all the initialisation cost (like compiling the stylesheet) is only incurred once.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use two Perl regular expression replaces, second one with marking groups and back-references, to reformat the header area of your XML files from

```xml
<SUBJECT>
  <TITLE>Mathematics</TITLE> 
  <AREA>
    <TITLE>Geometry</TITLE> 
    <SECTION>
      <TITLE>Coordinate Geometry</TITLE> 
      <TOPIC GRADELEVEL="10">
        <TITLE>Plotting Ordered Pairs </TITLE> 
        // Lots of content
      </TOPIC> 
    </SECTION> 
  </AREA> 
</SUBJECT>
```

to

```xml
<SUBJECT>
  <TITLE>Mathematics</TITLE>
</SUBJECT>
<AREA>
  <TITLE>Geometry</TITLE>
</AREA>
<SECTION>
  <TITLE>Coordinate Geometry</TITLE>
</SECTION>
<TOPIC GRADELEVEL="10">
  <TITLE>Plotting Ordered Pairs </TITLE>
</TOPIC>
        // Lots of content
```

So the block with *lots of content* is not unindented, but the other lines are as wanted on running this batch file from within the directory containing the *.xml files. Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` does not support Perl regular expression replaces in text files. For that reason is needed additionally [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid for reformatting the lines in the XML files using regular expression replaces. **JREPL.BAT** must be in same directory as this batch file.

```xml
@echo off
if not exist *.xml goto :EOF
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.xml /A-D /B') do (
    call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^[\t ]*</(?:AREA|SECTION|SUBJECT|TOPIC)>[\t ]*\r?\n" "" /M /F "%%I" /O -
    call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^[\t ]*<(AREA|SECTION|SUBJECT|TOPIC)(.*>)[\t ]*(\r?\n)[\t ]*(<TITLE>.*</TITLE>)[\t ]*$" "<$1$2$3  $4$3</$1>" /M /F "%%I" /O -
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`